# Plot distribution of a population AND the groups

Tags: python, seaborn

I would like to plot the age distribution of a population (total distribution) and the age distribution of each gender (Male, female). Each group contains a different number of persons (e.g. 40 Females, 32 Males). 
I am trying to do this with seaborn.distplot so that I can remove the bars and keep the curve only. I can plot the 3 curves but the frequencies are incorrect: the distribution curve for each gender should be smaller than the distribution of the total population.

We can consider that the dataset consist of 2 columns: 1 column contains the gender, the other the age.

Here is my code, column 0 contains gender and col 1 contains ages

```
sexes = ["Female", "Male"]
colors = ["orchid", "steelblue"]
ax = sns.distplot(df[:,0], color="k", hist = False, label = "Total")
for j, sexe in enumerate(sexes):
    ax = sns.distplot(df[:,1], color=colors[-j-1], hist = False, label = sexes_en[-j-1], norm_hist = True)
plt.show()
```

Comment: How does this code relate to what you want to do?

Comment: It plots the distributions for both gender and the total distribution. But not as I want it to be

Answer (score 0):

Here is a minimal example that do what you want :

```
pop = {"Gender" : ["M", "F", "F", "M"],
"Age" : [20, 25, 30, 22]}
df = pd.DataFrame(pop)
sexes = {"M": "Male", "F": "Female"}
colors = ["orchid", "steelblue"]
ax = sns.distplot(df["Age"], color="k", hist = False, label = "Total")
for color_idx, sexe in enumerate(set(df["Gender"])):
   ax = sns.distplot(df["Age"][df["Gender"] == sexe], color=colors[color_idx], hist = False, label = sexes[sexe])


plt.show()
```

I just renamed also the columns so it is more clear

Comment: Thank you for your help. However, the total distribution is not equal to the sum of the two "gender" distributions, that is the problem.

Comment: What do you mean by the total distribution? 
Can you give me a numerical example of what you expected ?